# MySQL Order By Symbol Preference

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, collation

I was wondering if there was a way to make alphanumeric characters have a higher order of preference than symbols when doing an ORDER BY.

I.E. 'a' to come before '('

There are many ways round this, but I'd prefer the most elegant db approach.

Comment: I think this is called "collation". http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-syntax.html

Comment: second that. here's how to define your custom collation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-collation-simple-8bit.html

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the required output.

```
SELECT <column_name> 
FROM <table_name> 
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN <column_name> REGEXP '^[a-z]' OR <column_name> REGEXP '^[A-Z]' THEN CONCAT('1',<column_name>) 
           WHEN <column_name> REGEXP '^[0-9]' THEN CONCAT('2',<column_name>) 
           ELSE CONCAT(3, <column_name>) 
         END;
```

It will first take up the alphabets, then numbers and lastly other characters.